# Magento 2.3.5-p1 upgrade to 2.4.0 problem

Tags: php, magento-upgrade, magento2.4

I am having problem when trying to upgrade in my dev server from Magento 2.3.5-p1 to 2.4.0 with composer.

I tried this:

```
composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update
composer update
cp composer.json composer.json.bak
composer remove magento/product-community-edition --no-update
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
composer update
```

After last

> composer update

I get error:

```
magento/framework 100.0.2 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.3 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.4 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.5 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.6 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.7 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.8 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.9 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.10 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.11 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.12 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.13 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.14 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.15 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.16 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.17 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.18 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.19 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.0.20 requires php ~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.0 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.1 requires php ~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.2 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.3 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.4 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.5 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.6 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.7 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.8 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.9 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.10 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.11 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.12 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.13 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.14 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.15 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.16 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.17 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 100.1.18 requires php ~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.0 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.1 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.2 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.3 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.4 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.5 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.6 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.7 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.8 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.9 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.10 requires php ~7.0.13|~7.1.0|~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 101.0.11 requires php ~7.0.13||~7.1.0||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.0 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.2 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - magento/framework 102.0.2-p2 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

I have in server php 7.3 version. I even tried with php 7.0. Couldn't make it work

What I do wrong please?

Comment: 1. check first is your composer.lock is updated. 2. Run search thru files and check is any of your module have old dependency for Magento framework 100.x  and 3. composer clear-cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if your `composer.json` doesn't have any specific restriction to the `magento/framework`, if you find something you can remove it. Then run these commands below.

```
rm composer.lock
composer update -vvv
```

If it doesn't work, I recommend changing your `composer.json` to be similar to the [native Magento 2.4 composer.json file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/composer.json).

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Upgrading Magento 2.3.5 to Magento 2.4 Requirement:**

Magento 2.4 support PHP 7.4 as per its offical document so before going to upgrade set require php version.

If you are planning to **upgrade Magento 2.3.5-p1 to Magento 2.4**, there are few changes that you need to do in your `composer.json`.

Run below command step by step to upgrade Magento 2.3.5 to Magento 2.4:

1-> `cp composer.json composer.json.bak` (this command create backup of composer.json. If you using windows, you can copy and paste the compose.json to create a backup copy)

2-> `composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update`

Now open `composer.json` file and do following required changes in version manually:

(a) `"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0"`

(b) `"magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0"`

(c) `"pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1"`

(d) `"phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0"`

(e) `"phpstan/phpstan": ">=0.12.3 <=0.12.23"`

(f) `"phpunit/phpunit": "^9"`

(g) `"sebastian/phpcpd": "~5.0.0"`

(h) `"squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4"`

(4) Run following command:

`composer update`

(5) Clear cache and regenerate code.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
 
rm -rf var/cache/*
 
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
 
rm -rf generated/code/*
 
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
  
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
  
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

(6) Last and final, disable Maintenance Mode

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

After completing this command, you have to run Magento setup upgrade, di compile , deploy command also .

**TESTED AND WORKING PROPERLY WITHOUT ERRORS**

If you get any issue with the upgrade, please comment below so I can help you.

**For Reference -**

1-> https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/upgrade-magento-version-2-3-x-2-4-0/

2-> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29350